# adding new article to DB not working

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, admin

im having a little trouble with my add.php page. I have tried many seperate codes but I am not sure why none of them seem to work.

None of the codes add to my database and it does not bring any reports back as I have error reporting turned on. So I am not sure why.

my code for my add.php page is:

```
    <?php

session_start();

include_once('../include/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
      if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
             $title = $_POST['title'];
             $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);
             $image = $_POST['Image URL'];
             $link = $_POST['Link'];
             $price = $_POST['Price'];

if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
             $error = 'All Fields Are Required!';
}else{
$query = $sql->prepare('INSERT INTO `xclocouk_mobile`.`mobi` (`promo_title`, `promo_content`, `promo_image`, `promo_link`, `promo_cat`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');
     $query->bindValue(1, $Title);
     $query->bindValue(2, $Content);
     $query->bindValue(3, $Image);
     $query->bindValue(4, $Link);
     $query->bindValue(5, $Category);

     $query->execute();
    header('location: index.php');

}

}
          ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../other.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

<br /><div align="center">


<h1>Add Article</h1>

<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
     <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small><br /><br />
<?php } ?>


<form name = "myform" action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">


<input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Title" /><br /><br />
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" name="Content" placeholder="Content"></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="Image" placeholder="Image URL" /><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="Link" placeholder="Link" /><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="Category" placeholder="Category" /><br /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Article" />

</form></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
}else{
       header('location: index.php');
}


?>
```

Does any one know why?

thank you.

Comment: It's posting to add.php so that'd be a good place to start looking.

Comment: that is my add.php page

Comment: I take it that add.php's code is the PHP block above the HTML tag?

Comment: the whole code above is what is on my add.php page

Comment: When you smash together your own stew of code, database calls and HTML, all kinds of things can and will go horribly wrong. Is there any reason you're not using a [popular PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) to make this more standardized and testable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are all lowercase, but when binding the values, you have the first letter capitalized.

Comment: ok I have changed them but all of a sudden I am getting this error message: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /add.php:1) in /add.php on line 3

Comment: Nothing can be sent to the browser prior to session_start().  Try taking out the line between <? and session_start(), and any spaces before <?.